# RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY - LoginTimers - Error 17830 logs when releasing unused database connection in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, oledb

I have this program  that uses QLOLEDB (also tried using the MSOLEDBSQL) to connect to local sql server express 2014 (ver 12.0.2). The program always creates 2 connections, one for IDBCreateCommand and one for iOpenRowset which is used for fastload. The program is functioning well but it keeps on creating RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY LoginTimers logs in sys.dm_os_ring_buffers when I try to release the database connections. No error were created in SQL server logs.

Using the SQL profiler, I know that the logging of RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY happens during Audit Logout of the database connection, though I have 2 connections, only one of them is creating the RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY log and it only happens when releasing connections that were not use (does not matter if it is using IDBCreateCommand or iOpenRowset). Using connections for running SQL query will not log RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY when they are released.

The issue is also happening in MS SQL server 2016 express (ver 13.0.4001) but not in MS SQL server 2012 express(ver 11.0.5058), I am really running out of ideas as to what is causing this. Is there some added feature in SQL server 2014 and later versions that warns user of unnecessary database connections that were created? Like connections that were created but not even use? (I tried proving this by creating database connections using MS SQL management studio then closing it afterwards and it does not create a RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY log... but looking at the sessions created using OLEDB and MS SQL management studio in sys.dm_exec_sessions.. sessions created using OLEDB has memory_usage = 0, while the latter has memory_usage = 3).

What am I missing?

Attached is the sample record created in sys.dm_os_ring_buffers.

[image: ring_buffer_connectivity_log]

Comment: Working on a similar issue now. My current theory is that two processes are using the same SPID. I have a SQL job that runs every minute and twice today i've seen it and a SharePoint process take the same spid at the same time. going to take me some more time to figure it out.

Comment: Hello, for those who are experiencing the same problem. I created a ticket about this and as per Microsoft Support:

[REG:119011819563458] RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY - LoginTimers - Error 17830 logs when releasing unused database connection in MS SQL

Issue definition
==========================================
RING_BUFFER_CONNECTIVITY - LoginTimers - Error 17830 logs when releasing unused database connection in MS SQL.

Comment: Troubleshooting
==============================
We found similar behavior for test connection, it is mostly by-design or the remaining compatibility issue. We double confirmed that the later versions of SQL Server will not support or maintain compatibility of this feature. We suggest don’t go making use of this DMV as an integral part of your monitoring solution but rather be mindful of it’s existence as a possible tool for ad-hoc use. If you encounter connectivity issue, we can use DBCC tracing/network tracing for another troubleshooting option. 
dbcc traceon(4029,-1)
dbcc traceon(3689,-1)

Comment: According to MS official article SQL Server Operating System Related Dynamic Management Views (Transact-SQL) :  “The following SQL Server Operating System-related dynamic management views are Identified for informational purposes only. Not supported. Future compatibility is not guaranteed.”
sys.dm_os_function_symbolic_name
sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
sys.dm_os_memory_allocations
sys.dm_os_sublatches
sys.dm_os_worker_local_storage

Comment: - You may also replicate the issue via these steps:

• And you can also replicate same issue with UDL test, Here I’m providing you with steps of this tests.
a) Open Notepad
b) Save the file as 'Connectivity Test.udl' and file type as 'All Files'
c) Open the saved file
d) Select Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server as the provider
e) Provide server connection and authentication details
f) Test the connection or open list of databases

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found 17830 State 107 loginTimer with  around 60 seconds to be closely correlated to clients attempting connection while they are under high CPU stress (unrelated to the SQL server CPU performance).  Increasing client side CPU resource in a vm environment has always reduced or eliminated this message from sys.dm_os_ring_buffers for me.